# oncomplete="processData(event.data)" causes "'data' is null or not an object"

Tags: javascript, jsf, richfaces

i found an example regarding how to use JSON with Richfaces but it's not working...i don't know if i'am missing something..
Here the code:

```
<h:form id="form1" prependId="false">

    <a4j:jsFunction 
        name="submitApplication"
        action="#{jsFunctionBean.actionMethod}"
        data="#{jsFunctionBean}"
        oncomplete="processData(event.data)" 
        immediate="true">
    </a4j:jsFunction>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        //example callback function with JSON data as argument
        function processData(data) {
            alert(data.test);
            alert(data.name);
        }

        //call the ajax method from javascript
        submitApplication();
    </script>

</h:form>
```

And the Bean:

@ManagedBean(name = "jsFunctionBean")
@SessionScoped

```
public class JsFunctionBean {

    /**
     * Test String name
     */
    private String name;

    public String getName() { return this.name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

    /**
     * Test boolean
     */
    private boolean test;
    public boolean getTest() { return this.test; }
    public void setTest(boolean test) { this.test = test; }    

    /**
     * Action Method 
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public String getActionMethod() {
        this.test = true;
        this.name = "Dave";
        return null;
    }


}
```

If i run this code the Alert is not displayed and i get the error "'data' is null or not an object" on the browser.
I am usign jsf 1.2 and richfaces 3.3.3.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I don't do RichFaces, but where exactly did you learn/read that the `event` argument object in the `oncomplete` handler has a `data` property? The error is pretty clear in that there is no such property. It's namely quite possible that you were actually reading a RichFaces 4.x targeted example and this thus won't necessarily work in RichFaces 3.x at all.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I checked the documentation and the data property is available also in rich faces 3.3.x.
http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/a4j_jsFunction.html

Comment: SOLUTION: i found the solution. My error was that "submitApplication" was never called...i added <body onload="submitApplication()"> in my page and then it works. One more thing, using my version of richfaces and jsf i changed oncomplete="processData(event.data)"  to oncomplete="processData(data)" to make it working.